# Trimming of Azimuth Frequency Extent After Stolt Interpolation

Tags: signal-analysis, radar

The space-variant impulse response can be circumvented by collecting SAR data over a larger angular aperture than is strictly needed to achieve the desired azimuth resolution. From Carrara's text, it mentions that the azimuth frequency extent can be trimmed at both ends after stolt interpolation of the Range Migration Algorithm (RMA). This process would allow the scatterers to fill a common processing aperture (rectangle for example).

I have two questions regarding this process:

1. Doesn't limiting the size of the processing aperture after stolt interpolation result in some loss of information? (Related to fundamental theory/concept)
2. Are there some guidelines to follow to know how much can be trimmed both along the azimuth and range directions?  (Related to methodology)

Any references that provide more details than the text from Carrara are much appreciated.

Added screenshots from the Carrara Text for reference
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do let me know if i have to rephrase my questions or add more details. I do understand that Synthetic Aperture Radar processing is somewhat a niche topic.

Comment: Hari, can you please add more details about the Carrara reference? Perhaps also some screenshots of the text you're asking about?

Comment: Sure I will add screenshots of the text I am referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. You are discarding some data in exchange for (theoretically) uniform IPRs. The amount of the information that is lost is usually considered minimal and worth the trade-off. For example, uniform IPRs with inscribed region of support in the frequency domain make doing SVA for the entire image at once straightforward.
2. The guideline to follow is that you keep the maximum inscribed frequency region that is common to all targets in the scene of interest. This will be determined by the targets at the far edges of the scene, where the least amount of rotation relative to the radar is observed.